# NodeJS | Express - Navigate back from root directory

Tags: node.js, express

My folder structure is:

project →  home → testscenario.xml

```
data=fs.readFileSync("./testscenario.xml","utf8");
```

**home** is set to be the **root** folder.
currently the testscenario.xml is in home folder.

If testscenario.xml is in the project folder how can i navigate one level up in express to access this file?

Comment: What does "home is set to be the root folder." mean?  There is no setting in node.js for "root folder", so I don't know what you mean by that.  So you mean "home" is the current directory in your app?  Or, do you mean it's the module directory?  I'd suggest you do `console.log(process.cwd())` and `console.log(__dirname)` from the place you want to read that file and that should then tell us what you can build off of to get the right path to the project directory.

Comment: yes home is the current directory. both console logs printed the same path in the console

Comment: what exactly did they print?

Comment: They printed the same path. 
`C:\Users\dinesh\Desktop\project\home`using `/../` before the file name I was able to navigate to project folder `data=fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/../testscenario.xml","utf8");`
did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"home is set to be the root folder."**

I take the meaning of this sentence as **Your .js file is under the same directory of testscenario.xml**

Now, **If testscenario.xml is in the project folder**,

using `__dirname` to handle the path:

`data=fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/../testscenario.xml","utf8");`

Comment: I figured it out and came here to post the answer. Yes you are right, currently the testscenario.xml is in home folder and I needed it to be in project folder. Using /../ did the trick. Thanks.